# Android contacts IM information

Tags: android

How can I get all the IM userIDs stored for a certain contact (AIM, yahoo etc.) regardless of their type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user ID or Handle is the field ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA. Here's an [example](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/rde8026-android/UberAddressBook/src/com/uberaddressbook/queries/PersonActivities.java). Jump to the method getPersonIM() for the code.